# Timestamp from Firebase to String date

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp

I have a Timestamp model and get a Timestamp from Firebase.
`print(user.endDate.toDate());` = `flutter: 2020-08-05 00:00:01.000`
A newbe question, but I'm struggling with what I should user here: `Text(?)` to get the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the time class

example:

```
//before we show the date we need to parse it then show it in a format Month 2 , 2020

     Container(
    child: Text(new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.parse(productInfo["createdAt"]))),
               ),

// this is your time => productInfo["createdAt"]
```

[DateTime class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Timestamp firestoreTimestamp = data['timestamp'];
DateTime dateTime = firestoreTimestamp.toDate();

Text(dateTime.toString());
```

Comment: Although your solution might solve the problem, please add an explanation as to why it works to make it more effective